# Is there any method to create custom tags and filter with these in Full Calender

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I was making a clone of the **calender**. So, I chose the [fullcalender](https://fullcalendar.io/) to do that. As far as I could see, all things that I needed are there, except the filter. Anyone knows how to do that?

The Calendar image is what I want:

[image]

Briefly. There are different staff for event. I want some technique so I would add the staff id related to the event attribute. And, when I filter by that attribute it will show that events only.

Comment: It should be done with your database. You must be using a table for events. You might need to create one table (e.g. Staff Events) storing foreign keys to staff id and event id (from events table). Than you should apply a join with events table while retrieving the data for the FullCalendar.

Comment: This sounds like an ideal use case for the Scheduler add-on. See the demos linked from https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view to understand how it might help you. If you would rather not pay for this functionality, then you'd have to code it yourself. As the above comment notes, the easiest way to do a filter would be to have your event feed filter the data - changing the option in the dropdown would simply trigger the event feed to refresh but using the newly selected user ID as a parameter.

Comment: @KhurramIshaque I like your suggestion. this is the best i can guess.